# Jquery does work on JSfiddle but doesnt on server

Tags: jquery

i have a basic jquery and html code, when i paste in in JSfiddle and select the library "jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" it works. But when i dont select a library, but link a script from my server it doesn't work...

I checked the request, and the server gave an answer with the correct library...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#NewCustomerDiv input[name="companyname"]').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
            } else {
                $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
        if ($('#NewCustomerDiv input[name="companyname"]').val()) {
            $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
        }
        $(".compname").click(function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="NewCustomerDiv" <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel field0a">Bedrijfsnaam</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel field0b" colspan="3">
        <input type="text" name="companyname" tabindex="3" style="width:80%;" />
        <p style="margin-left:50px; display:inline;">Indien van toepassing</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <div id="CustomerCompanyDiv" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="veld1" />
        <input type="text" name="veld2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd5U/)

Comment: Did you forget to import the jQuery library on your server?

Comment: care to share the link you used to your jquery library? i have a feeling your link is either wrong or you dont have access to it

Comment: So there are td and tr inside a div ? Consider uisng div with css "`display:table-row` > `display:table-cell` instead `;)`

Comment: Open fiddle width chrome console or firebug,check the network tag,see if your jquery link load failed.

Comment: Provide the url of your jquery library on your server please

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the link to the server. I'm not allowed to do that due security reasons. But i know the link is right. I checked it with firebug and the request get an answer

Answer (score 2):

Did you included the JQ file at the top of the page ?

May be the problem is because you didn't closed the opening of this tag : (line 24)

```
<div id="NewCustomerDiv"
```

Also You have to put the table tags (`tr` , `td`) into `<table>` tag.

---

### Check this : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd5U/2/)

Comment: yes i know but this was pure for trying, normally my code is well i think, but i'm going to try it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the first `<div>` and forget the `<table>` tag

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcd5U/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="NewCustomerDiv">
    <table>    
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldlabel field0a">Bedrijfsnaam</td>
            <td class="fieldlabel field0b" colspan="3">
                <input type="text" name="companyname" tabindex="3" style="width:80%;" /> 
                <p style="margin-left:50px; display:inline;">Indien van toepassing</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <div id="CustomerCompanyDiv" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="veld1" />
        <input type="text" name="veld2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#NewCustomerDiv input[name="companyname"]').keyup(function(){    
         if($(this).val()==""){
              $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
         }
         else{
            $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideDown("slow");
         }
    });

    if($('#NewCustomerDiv input[name="companyname"]').val()){
         $('#CustomerCompanyDiv').slideUp("slow");
    }

    $(".compname").click(function(){
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```